# Simulink Coder: How to specify custom C files from script when generating C code?

Tags: matlab, simulink, matlab-coder

I have a script that does some post processing of the initial code generated by Simulink coder.  It creates an `additional.c` file that I wish to add into the build process.  I want to add the file into the build process from a script, so I am following [the docs here](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/stateflow/ug/using-the-command-line-api-to-set-parameters-for-simulation-and-embeddable-code-generation.html).

So my script looks like:

```
slbuild(gcs);
% generate additional.c file using files created by slbuild()
% ...
% now attempt to add additional.c to the build process as custom code
configs = getActiveConfigSet(gcs);
configs.set_param('SimUserSources', 'additional.c');
% now rebuild
slbuild(gcs)
```

I can verify that the config set is updated by:

```
checkConfigIsSet = configs.get_param('SimUserSources'); 
disp(checkConfigIsSet); % prints: additional.c
```

However, the coder does not appear to pick up this new config.  When I click on the `Configuration settings at the time of code generation: click to open` section of the Code Generation report, I see the config value was not updated and `additional.c` was not compiled into the model.

What am I doing wrong please?

Answer (score 1):

SimUserSources are for simulation builds used by blocks like MATLAB Function block and Stateflow. For code generation, you need to set the param "CustomSource". Try,

```
slbuild(gcs);
% generate additional.c file using files created by slbuild()
% ...
% now attempt to add additional.c to the build process as custom code
configs = getActiveConfigSet(gcs);
configs.set_param('CustomSource', 'additional.c');
% now rebuild
slbuild(gcs)
```